# How to correctly output an image to the template in Django?

Tags: html, django, image, templates

The image of the page is not displayed. Most likely I am incorrectly specifying the path to the image file. Please tell me what I should fix in my code?

Code in the template

```html
<main>
  {% block content %}
  <p>
    <img src="../outputs/imgoutputs/14.jpg" width="189" height="255" alt="lorem">
  </p>
  {% endblock %}
</main>
```

Approximate project structure:

project
-generate(app)
-views.py
-outputs
-imgoutputs
-14.jpg
-templates
-thankyou.html

Help me please to correctly specify the path to the image.

Answer (score 1):

For your image to show up the official way is to use the static tag, so something like that :

```
<img src="{% static 'outputs/imgoutputs/14.jpg' %}" alt="My image"/>
```

This suppose that your image is inside static/outputs/imgoutputs/14.jpg

Don't forget to add {% load static %}

You do not need the static folder, Django knows how to find your image.